# Acumatica - Shrink text to fit Textbox

Tags: report, acumatica

I have a label that prints out Stock Item info, and will go on a bin that stores that item.

Q:  Some descriptions are longer than others.  Is there a "shrink to fit" feature for Acumatica Report text fields?   In other words, I'd like the text to fi tin the text box.  If a short description, the font will be larger.  The longer the description, the smaller the font so that it fits in the textbox.

I feel I have seen it with a 3rd party add in, however this isn't something new so was hoping I was just missing something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available in the Report designer.

The closest functionality available is the **CanGrow** property that expands the control size vertically to display the whole value.

[image]

Comment: That is what I was concluding as well, but I was hoping I was missing something   
Thank you though for checking.